# Telegram Bot, проверить успешность выполнения sendMessage

Tags: telegram-bot

Есть ли возможность гарантировано определить, выполнил ли успешно сервер команду [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage). В нормальных условиях сервер, в случае успеха, возвращает [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message). Как быть, если ответ по каким то причинам не был принят клиентом (сбой сети, перезапуск клиента).

Comment: Не нашел прямого метода, как вариант: https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.search указать `max_id` равный `id` нужного сообщения и `limit` равный `1`

Answer (score 1):

При отправке сообщения ни [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots), ни [MtProto](https://core.telegram.org/api#telegram-api) не обрабатывают ошибки, произошедшие на другом конце, у получателя. Это полностью забота сервера телеграм и клиента получателя.

Если сервер Telegram не вернул ошибку на `sendMessage`*, это значит, что сообщение принято в обработку, и оно достигнет получателя, как только он станет онлайн. Выяснить, прочитано ли сообщение или нет — нельзя.

* Подразумевается, что в ответ мы получили JSON-объект у которого поле `ok` равно true.

Comment: Вопрос в том, что если сервер возвращал JSON объект с полем OK=true, но ответ не удалось получить (сбой сети), каким образом можно после восстановления связи определить успешность операции.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, вообще говоря никак, ведь API для ботов не позволяет получать отправленные сообщения. И не важно, на каком участке произошёл сбой: на пути от бота к телеграм или от телеграма к получателю